# Recyclerview to fold or unfold, what I do to at this step?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

**CODE :**

```
public class TimelineFragment extends Fragment {


    PostViewAdapter postViewAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View baseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container, false);
        ArrayList<Postitem> listitem = new ArrayList<>();

        RecyclerView rvList = (RecyclerView) baseView.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);

        for (int i = 0; i<30; i++) {
            Postitem item = new Postitem();
             listitem.add(i, item);
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) baseView.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        postViewAdapter = new PostViewAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postViewAdapter);


        return baseView;
    }
    class PostViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View baseView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);

            PostViewHolder postViewHolder = new PostViewHolder(baseView);
            return postViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200
            );
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params_open = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 30;
        }
    }

    class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView iv_red, iv_yellow;

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_yellow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_yellow);
            iv_red = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_red);
            iv_red.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final int position = getLayoutPosition();
        }
    }
}
```

These code is for **Recyclerview** on Fragment.

That shows 30 post_item.

What is you have to notice is this.

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200
            );
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params_open = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

I made this for view to fold or unfold.

I want to use this for each itemview, so I want to make effect that is like fold or unfold each **itemview**.

I thought I have to set onClickListener on iv_red, so I made

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final int position = getLayoutPosition();
    }
```

But i don't know what I do after that.

anyone have an idea ? Please help me

**Edit**

Sorry, i missed many things. Now i'm making android application that gave data from server.

The data from server is like {"text":"blahblah", "image":SomethingImageUrl"}. And i wanna show this data in RecyclerView ListLayout.

But acctually what i want is item of the ListLayout is shown only text first, end user click shown text, the image which was hiden is show up to that user. I.e.

It's like other application's(like instagram or facebook) see more function.

The problem is how to set onclicklistener for each item of Recyclerview, to apply LayoutParams. Even i added OnclickListener to my PostViewHolder, I don't know about it anymore.

Comment: It is good that you gave an example in code but people need more context before reading everything. what are you doing? what is the goal? what is the problem?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy, sorry, i missed many things. Now i'm making android application that gave data from server. The data from server is like {"text":"blahblah", "image":SomethingImageUrl"}. And i wanna show this data in RecyclerView ListLayout. But acctually what i want is item of the ListLayout is shown only text first, end user click shown text, the image which was hiden is show up to that user. I.e. It's like other application's(like instagram or facebook) `see more` function. The problem is how to set onclicklistener for each item of Recyclerview, to apply LayoutParams.

Comment: If it's too boring, i will just have thanks for your first comment.

Comment: just add that to your question to make it more clear

Comment: @NathanMcCoy Thank you, i added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve your problem rapidly, you can add an external library in your project. 
Searching on internet I’ve found a library available on github:

https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android

Firstly put this code in your Grandle:

```
implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.3'
```

Finally follow step by step the instructions shown in the main page.